# What registers does strcmp evaluate? x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

It seems like this is common knowledge, but I can't find it written on the internet (yet).

When a program has

```
call <JMP.&msvcrt.strcmp>
```

what values are compared? I'm unsure because with cmp it's stated (cmp eax, ebp).

I know the result of the comparison is returned in the EAX register if that helps.

Comment: 'call' transfers the control to the address of the library routine, strcmp, which is not an intrinsic assembly instruction (like cmp). Therefore, the value returned / compared depends on the function signature/language, calling convention, etc. Unless you're good at reverse engineering, you would most likely have to find the original prototype of the function which states where/how/which arguments are passed.

Comment: I updated my question after looking at it in a different debugger. 
It's msvcrt's strcmp

Comment: For standard calling conventions on x86, arguments are pushed to the stack before calling the function. On x64, some arguments may be passed in registers instead. Immideately before, you should see some instructions pushing registers on to the stack in the case of x86, or some movement in the registers for x64 (may be harder to see).
Again, you cannot correctly identify what values are used and how, without having the exact function signature and system architechture. And even then, the compiler may optimize however it feels.

Comment: I see the values pushed to the stack now, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to associate `strcmp` with the assembly instruction `cmp`. But they are different things. In the processor level (assembly), the `cmp A, B` compares 2 different registers, for example, and set the result in some flags. Flags are bits that can be tested by other instructions (like `jz`, `jnz`) and then redirect the flow according to the desired intention.

When you do a `call strcmp` you are actually calling a "high level function" (*high level, when compared to assembly*) that will perform a lot of stuff to compare 2 C-Style strings. It's not easy to know which registers will be used (many of them will be used probably), once each compiler/platform will give a different result of machine instructions.

And if you understand this, you will see that it doesn't matter in fact, because the paradigm is a little different:

- `cmp` is an assembly instruction.
- `strcmp` is not an assembly instruction, but a function.

Comment: Thanks, you're answer combined with the comments given already means I need to look to the values being put on the stack.